# Create a Custom User in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, useradd

I want to create a user in the FreeBSD for `nginx` that has:

- No Login.
- No home directory

how should I do that with `pw useradd` or any other tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must have a home directory listed in `/etc/passwd`. Usually that will be whatever directory you store the web pages / config files in, though if you want to make sure it's a directory that doesn't exist, `/nonexistent` can be used instead.

To create a user that is not allowed to login, you would do two things:

- give the user a shell that is not allowed to login
- set the password to disallow login

This is how you do it:

```
useradd -c "Nginx server account" -d /path/to/directory -s /usr/sbin/nologin -w no nginx
```